# Javascript, como mostrar unicamente dos decimales

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quiero que al hacer el calculo me aparezcan dos decimales, ya que por ejemplo ingreso la cantidad `100` y al calcular en los demás campos aparecen muchos decimales. Ya intente hacerlo con `.toFixed(2)` y no logro hacer que funcione.

Ilustración y código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
//funcion que se ejecuta cada vez que se añade una letra en un cuadro de texto
//suma los valores de los cuadros de texto

function sumar()
{
    var dolar = 18;
 var porcentaje = 100;
 var valor1=verificar("valor1");
 var valor2=verificar("valor2");
 var valor3=verificar("valor3");
 var valor4=verificar("valor4");
 var valor5=verificar("valor5");
 x = parseFloat(valor1);
 y = parseFloat(valor1)/parseFloat(dolar);
 z = parseFloat(valor1)/porcentaje*10/parseFloat(dolar);
 f = parseFloat(y)+parseFloat(z);

 // realizamos la suma de los valores y los ponemos en la casilla del
 // formulario que contiene el total

 document.getElementById("valor2").value= x;
 document.getElementById("valor3").value= y;
 document.getElementById("valor4").value= z; 
 document.getElementById("valor5").value= f;
}

//funcion para verificar los valores de los cuadros de texto. si no es un valor
//numerico, cambia de color el borde del cuadro de texto
function verificar(id)
{
    var obj=document.getElementById(id);
    if(obj.value=="")
     value="0";
 else
     value=obj.value;
    if(validate_importe(value,1))
 {
     // marcamos como erroneo
  obj.style.borderColor="#808080";
  return value;
 }else{
     // marcamos como erroneo
  obj.style.borderColor="#f00";
  return 0;
 }
}

//Funcion para validar el importe
//Tiene que recibir: El valor del importe
//Determinar si permite o no decimales
//Devuelve: true - Correcto , False - Incorrecto
function validate_importe(value,decimal)
{
    if(decimal==undefined)
     decimal=0;
 if(decimal==1)
 {
     // Permite decimales tanto por . como por ,
  var patron=new RegExp("^[0-9]+((,|\.)[0-9]{1,2})?$");
 }else{
  // Numero entero normal
  var patron=new RegExp("^([0-9])*$")
 }

 if(value && value.search(patron)==0)
 {
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```

```css
.auto-style1 { text-align: center; }
  .auto-style2 { background-image: url('http://remesasenvia.com/img/bg_calculo_pesos_blanco.jpg');  }
  .auto-style3 { border-width: 0px; }
  .auto-style4 { text-align: left; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
  .auto-style5 { font-size: 55pt; }
  .auto-style6 { text-align: left; }
  .auto-style7 { text-align: left; font-family: Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 55pt; }
  .auto-style8 { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
  .auto-style9 { font-size: 55pt; font-weight: bold; }
  .auto-style10 { text-align: right; }
  .auto-style11 { font-size: 55pt; color: #00A743; }
```

```html
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['user']){
 header ("Location: ingresar.php");
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <title>Remesas Envia - Calculo En Pesos</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  .auto-style1 { text-align: center; }
  .auto-style2 { background-image: url('http://remesasenvia.com/img/bg_calculo_pesos_blanco.jpg');  }
  .auto-style3 { border-width: 0px; }
  .auto-style4 { text-align: left; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
  .auto-style5 { font-size: 55pt; }
  .auto-style6 { text-align: left; }
  .auto-style7 { text-align: left; font-family: Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 55pt; }
  .auto-style8 { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
  .auto-style9 { font-size: 55pt; font-weight: bold; }
  .auto-style10 { text-align: right; }
  .auto-style11 { font-size: 55pt; color: #00A743; }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript"src="/js/calculopesos.js"></script>
 </head>

<body style="background-color: #E06716; height: 1648px; margin-top: 27px;">

<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 940px; height: 1560px" class="auto-style2">
   <tr>
     <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 940px; height: 230px" colspan="2"></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
               <td class="auto-style10" style="width: 538px; height: 170px;">
      <input type="number" id="valor1" size="23" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 85pt; height: 160px; width: 410px;" class="auto-style11" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
               <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 470px; height: 170px;">
      <img alt height="168" onclick="sumar()" src="http://remesasenvia.com/img/button_calcula.jpg" style="float: left" width="370" class="auto-style11"></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
   <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 940px; height: 1110px;" colspan="2">
   <p class="auto-style4"><span class="auto-style5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Si envias a Mexico</span></p>
      <div class="auto-style6"><span class="auto-style5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="auto-style8"><strong>$</strong></span></span>

      <strong>

    <input type="text" id="valor2" value="0.00" disabled value="0" size="23" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 55pt; height: 75px; width: 335px;" required class="auto-style9"></strong>
    <span class="auto-style7">pesos</span></div>

      <p class="auto-style4"><span class="auto-style5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; tu familia recibe</span></p>
      <div class="auto-style6"><span class="auto-style5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="auto-style8"><strong>$</strong></span></span>

    <strong>

    <input type="text" id="valor3" value="0.00" disabled value="0" size="23" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 55pt; height: 75px; width: 335px;" required class="auto-style9"></strong>
    <span class="auto-style7">dolares</span></div>

   <p class="auto-style4"><span class="auto-style5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; tu envio cuesta</span></p>
      <div class="auto-style6"><span class="auto-style5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="auto-style8"><strong>$</strong></span></span>

    <strong>

    <input type="text" id="valor4" value="0.00" disabled value="0" size="23" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 55pt; height: 75px; width: 335px;" required class="auto-style9"></strong>
    <span class="auto-style7">dolares</span></div>

   <p class="auto-style4"><span class="auto-style5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; tu pago total es de</span></p>
      <div class="auto-style6"><span class="auto-style5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="auto-style8"><strong>$</strong></span></span>

    <strong>

    <input type="text" id="valor5" value="0.00" disabled value="0" size="23" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 55pt; height: 75px; width: 335px;" required class="auto-style9"></strong>
    <span class="auto-style7">dolares</span></div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <a name="envio" href="seleccionar_destinatario.php"><img alt height="200" src="http://remesasenvia.com/img/button_continuar.jpg" width="850" class="auto-style3" /></a></td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
     <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 940px; height: 45px" colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: utiliza `numero.toFixed(2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes ver esta misma pregunta en la versión inglesa [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places). 
El siguiente código debería funcionarte: `parseFloat(Math.round(num1 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);`.

```js
//funcion que se ejecuta cada vez que se añade una letra en un cuadro de texto
//suma los valores de los cuadros de texto

function sumar()
{
  var dolar = 18;
  var porcentaje = 100;
  var valor1=verificar("valor1");
  var valor2=verificar("valor2");
  var valor3=verificar("valor3");
  var valor4=verificar("valor4");
  var valor5=verificar("valor5");
  x = parseFloat(valor1);
  y = parseFloat(valor1)/parseFloat(dolar);
  z = parseFloat(valor1)/porcentaje*10/parseFloat(dolar);
  f = parseFloat(y)+parseFloat(z);

        // Bloque para dar formato a los campos.
        x = parseFloat(Math.round(x * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
        y = parseFloat(Math.round(y * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
        z = parseFloat(Math.round(z * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
        f = parseFloat(Math.round(f * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

  // realizamos la suma de los valores y los ponemos en la casilla del
  // formulario que contiene el total

  document.getElementById("valor2").value= x;

     document.getElementById("valor3").value= y;

  document.getElementById("valor4").value= z;
  
     document.getElementById("valor5").value= f;

}

//funcion para verificar los valores de los cuadros de texto. si no es un valor
//numerico, cambia de color el borde del cuadro de texto

function verificar(id)
{
  var obj=document.getElementById(id);
  if(obj.value=="")
    value="0";
  else
    value=obj.value;
  if(validate_importe(value,1))
  {
    // marcamos como erroneo
    obj.style.borderColor="#808080";
    return value;
  }else{
    // marcamos como erroneo
    obj.style.borderColor="#f00";
    return 0;
  }
}

//Funcion para validar el importe
//Tiene que recibir: El valor del importe
//Determinar si permite o no decimales
//Devuelve: true - Correcto , False - Incorrecto

function validate_importe(value,decimal)
{
  if(decimal==undefined)
    decimal=0;

  if(decimal==1)
  {
    // Permite decimales tanto por . como por ,
    var patron=new RegExp("^[0-9]+((,|\.)[0-9]{1,2})?$");
  }else{
    // Numero entero normal
    var patron=new RegExp("^([0-9])*$")
  }

  if(value && value.search(patron)==0)
  {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
.auto-style1 { text-align: center; }
  .auto-style2 { background-image: url('http://remesasenvia.com/img/bg_calculo_pesos_blanco.jpg');  }
  .auto-style3 { border-width: 0px; }
  .auto-style4 { text-align: left; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
  .auto-style5 { font-size: 55pt; }
  .auto-style6 { text-align: left; }
  .auto-style7 { text-align: left; font-family: Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 55pt; }
  .auto-style8 { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
  .auto-style9 { font-size: 55pt; font-weight: bold; }
  .auto-style10 { text-align: right; }
  .auto-style11 { font-size: 55pt; color: #00A743; }
```

```html
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['user']){
 header ("Location: ingresar.php");
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <title>Remesas Envia - Calculo En Pesos</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  .auto-style1 { text-align: center; }
  .auto-style2 { background-image: url('http://remesasenvia.com/img/bg_calculo_pesos_blanco.jpg');  }
  .auto-style3 { border-width: 0px; }
  .auto-style4 { text-align: left; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
  .auto-style5 { font-size: 55pt; }
  .auto-style6 { text-align: left; }
  .auto-style7 { text-align: left; font-family: Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 55pt; }
  .auto-style8 { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
  .auto-style9 { font-size: 55pt; font-weight: bold; }
  .auto-style10 { text-align: right; }
  .auto-style11 { font-size: 55pt; color: #00A743; }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript"src="/js/calculopesos.js"></script>
 </head>

<body style="background-color: #E06716; height: 1648px; margin-top: 27px;">

<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 940px; height: 1560px" class="auto-style2">
   <tr>
     <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 940px; height: 230px" colspan="2"></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
               <td class="auto-style10" style="width: 538px; height: 170px;">
      <input type="number" id="valor1" size="23" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 85pt; height: 160px; width: 410px;" class="auto-style11" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
               <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 470px; height: 170px;">
      <img alt height="168" onclick="sumar()" src="http://remesasenvia.com/img/button_calcula.jpg" style="float: left" width="370" class="auto-style11"></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
   <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 940px; height: 1110px;" colspan="2">
   <p class="auto-style4"><span class="auto-style5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Si envias a Mexico</span></p>
      <div class="auto-style6"><span class="auto-style5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="auto-style8"><strong>$</strong></span></span>

      <strong>

    <input type="text" id="valor2" value="0.00" disabled value="0" size="23" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 55pt; height: 75px; width: 335px;" required class="auto-style9"></strong>
    <span class="auto-style7">pesos</span></div>

      <p class="auto-style4"><span class="auto-style5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; tu familia recibe</span></p>
      <div class="auto-style6"><span class="auto-style5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="auto-style8"><strong>$</strong></span></span>

    <strong>

    <input type="text" id="valor3" value="0.00" disabled value="0" size="23" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 55pt; height: 75px; width: 335px;" required class="auto-style9"></strong>
    <span class="auto-style7">dolares</span></div>

   <p class="auto-style4"><span class="auto-style5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; tu envio cuesta</span></p>
      <div class="auto-style6"><span class="auto-style5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="auto-style8"><strong>$</strong></span></span>

    <strong>

    <input type="text" id="valor4" value="0.00" disabled value="0" size="23" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 55pt; height: 75px; width: 335px;" required class="auto-style9"></strong>
    <span class="auto-style7">dolares</span></div>

   <p class="auto-style4"><span class="auto-style5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; tu pago total es de</span></p>
      <div class="auto-style6"><span class="auto-style5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="auto-style8"><strong>$</strong></span></span>

    <strong>

    <input type="text" id="valor5" value="0.00" disabled value="0" size="23" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 55pt; height: 75px; width: 335px;" required class="auto-style9"></strong>
    <span class="auto-style7">dolares</span></div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <a name="envio" href="seleccionar_destinatario.php"><img alt height="200" src="http://remesasenvia.com/img/button_continuar.jpg" width="850" class="auto-style3" /></a></td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
     <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 940px; height: 45px" colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cuánto texto duplicado solo para decir que debería utilizar `toFixed`...

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Hecnabae. Me ayudaste bastante.